# Source path too long popup while deleting folders in Windows

Tags: windows

How to delete files that says "source path too long" I could not able to delete a folder completely from my computer because one of the files in the folder is giving out error "Source Path too long for delete".

Operating system : Windows 7

Answer (score 2):

The windows command called robocopy worked for me.

1.Open the command prompt with Administrator mode

2.Create one new folder on same location where that "to be deleted folder" is located

3.Go to the path where we have these two folders and type below command
robocopy   /purge

this will empty all the contents in the tobedeletedfolder

4. Now delete both the folder